# Querying Lucene Special Character followed by a number

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have a document that has a searchable field. The value of that field is: "CAM CAM Nursery Bag / Nappy Bag + Essentials Set Grey (6 pieces)"

When I preform a search on this exact phrase I get no hits, search for most parts of it will return it as a hit. 
Special Characters are set up using:
`searchText = QueryParserBase.Escape(searchText);`

If I remove (6 from the query then it matches. If I change (6 => (a in both the source data added to the document and in the query it matches.

It seems like lucene doesn't know how to handle a special character followed by a number, but I don't know why that would make any difference.

I would rather not search for this exact use case to remove it from queries if at all possible. I would like if someone searched with this level of specific that it matched correctly.

Comment: What analyzer are you using, and how are you constructing the search?

Comment: We are using the IndexAnalyzer with StandardTokenizer StandardFilter, LowerCaseFilter, SynonymFilter, StopFilter, and EdgeNGramTokenFilter

The search is set up using MultiFieldQueryParser.
The only things we do to the incoming text are lowercase it and escape it.

Comment: That's not a trivial analyzer. For example what are your stops?  Do notice with a Whitespace analyzer, you would get the accuracy you desire, so this isn't a case of "lucene doesn't know how to handle special characters".  Take a look at the token stream generated, or tear down the filters and build up until you find the issue. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Looks like the issue is solely in the NgramFilter. We're using a min gram of 3. If we reduce it to 1 it returns it.
I'll have to do some research on how exactly Ngram works and probe my coworker who implemented that to see if I can avoid having to break my index into chunks of 1 and still get my response back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this wasn't a case of it not finding (6 because of the special code.
I still don't totally understand why it could find (a if I changed it to that. But whatever.

The problem was the EdgeNgramFilter I was using has the minGram set to 3 and so search terms that were 2 and under were breaking our code. Solution was to remove all of these from the search text before we escaped the search text and before we parsed and searched it.